# ESLint is Extremely Touchy

Tags: vuejs2, eslint

I apologize as I can't think of the word I'm looking for, but I have a default vue 2.0 project through the vue cli. I allowed ESLint, in order to help with typing. I'm not entirely sure what it is used for, other than pissing someone off at this point.

For example,

```
functionName() {} <-- no space after functionName is causing a runtime error

AnotherFunc () {
var thisthing = '' <-- You suck for not using another 4 spaces
    ///Comment <--- expected a space to begin comment after ///
```

I mean, this is kind of ridiculous. What do I gain from this? How do I get the es6 intellisense without these ludicrous formatting requirements?

Comment: https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit `.eslintrc.js` and

replace:

`extends: 'standard'`

with:

`extends: 'eslint:recommended'`

then your linter should be more relaxed.

In order to disable specific rules, check [this list](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/) and edit `rules` property in `.eslintrc.js`.